# How to switch between jQuery versions on two pages

Tags: jquery, version, compatibility

I have a functionality that works fine under jQuery 1.7. But another functionality on a different page that breaks and needs jQuery 1.4.2.

How do I effectively switch from 1.7 to 1.4.2 when the page with the 1.4.2 functionality loads?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I would strongly suggest that you try to see what the problem with that plugin or piece of code that you say "it breaks" using the newest version of jQuery.

nevertheless, you can always load several versions of jQuery on the same page and treat them differently, for example:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // loads latest jQuery (1.7.2)
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $("#hello").text($.fn.jquery);
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // loads jQuery 1.4.2
    var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq142("#hello2").text(jq142.fn.jquery);
</script>
```

[Live example on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ugejit/edit#javascript,html)

Answer (score 1):

The question has nothing to do with JQuery. You need to program your server to serve the correct JQuery file for that particular page. Depending on your server and the language your pages are in (PHP, C#, Ruby, Perl, CFM? Or maybe it's SSI or JSP?), the answers will vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery noConflict for this, here  is an article about it
http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

I would however not recommend this, just fix the bugs, you will be walking into a world of pain if you are going to load jQuery versions on a per plugin basis, a world of pain, seriously.